# What is the total variation of sin over an arbitrary interval?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find the total variation of $\sin$ over $[a,b]$. Just playing around with it, it would seem that $\int_a^b|\sin(x)|dx$ gives the correct answer, but I'm unsure of how I could show that to be the case. If that's not correct, then how else can I approach the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, since the total variation on $[0,\frac{5\pi}2]$, for example, must be 5. Maybe you're using a different definition of variation, because I'm completely confused.

Comment: I messed up, my bad, but my actual answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

For any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, between $k\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $(k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ the sine function is monotonic and has a total variation equal to $1$, hence over some interval $[a,b]$ the total variation is bounded by:
$$\left\lceil\frac{2}{\pi}|b-a|\right\rceil.$$
Obviously the exact value of the total variation on $[a,b]$ depends on the positions of $\min\left([a,b]\cap\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{Z}\right)$ and $\max\left([a,b]\cap\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbb{Z}\right)$ with respect to the endpoints of $[a,b]$.